# Multiplying two images with openCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I m multiplying two 16U DEPTH / 3 channels images with openCV via:
cvMul(*src1, *src2, *dest, 1)

What would be the destination properties? 16U, 3 Ch as well?

Comment: have you tried it? were there any errors? have you looked up the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dest will also have a depth of 3

Comment: In [general](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cvmul#multiply), both inputs and the destination must have the same type and depth.