# Issues in Multiplying two RGB images in opencv using c++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix-multiplication

I want to multiply one image by its transpose. my image size is nxm.
i do as follows

```
    for (int k = 0; k < total_images; k++)
{
    Mat img_tp1 = cv::Mat(imgRows, imgCols, CV_32FC1);
    Mat img_tp2 = cv::Mat(imgRows, imgRows, CV_32FC1);

    subtract(img[k], MeanMat, img_tp1);
    img_tp2 = img_tp1 * img_tp2.t();
    std::ostringstream name;
    name << "sub" << k << ".jpg";
    cv::imwrite(name.str(), img_tp2);
}
```

and i face this error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFDB79E5D in Tracking.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000001E5EE0.
```

how can i do this multiplication? in fact i want to compute the covariance matrix of the sequence of images so i need this multiplication.
Thanks.

Then i decide to implement the multiplying for my RGB image and i use this code:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < imgRows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgRows; j++)
        {
            uchar pix1[3];
            uchar pix2[3];
            uchar pix[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

            for (int k = 0; k < imgCols; k++)
            {
                img_tp1.at<Vec3b>(i, k) = { pix1[0], pix1[1], pix1[2] };
                img_tp1.at<Vec3b>(j, k) = { pix2[0], pix2[1], pix2[2] };
                CovMat0.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = { pix[0], pix[1], pix[2] };
                pix[0] = (pix1[0] * pix2[0]) + pix[0];
                pix[1] = (pix1[1] * pix2[1]) + pix[1];
                pix[2] = (pix1[2] * pix2[2]) + pix[2];
                CovMat0.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = { pix[0], pix[1], pix[2] };
            }
        }
    }
```

but it takes lots of time to process it. Is there any better way for that?
(I want to multiply one image by its transpose)

Comment: Check out the comments provided [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601241/opencv-multiply-images-in-c-and-c?rq=1) and also [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658977/multiplying-two-images-with-opencv?rq=1)

Comment: Is it a single channel image, And I dont think this would generate any desired results, What do you exactly want to do by multiplying the image with it's transpose

Comment: It is RGB image so it has 3channels. I want to compute  the covariance matrix of the sequence of images.

Comment: fix `Mat img_tp2 = cv::Mat(imgRows, imgRows, CV_32FC1)` to `Mat img_tp2 = cv::Mat(imgRows, imgCols, CV_32FC1)`

Comment: actually the multiply matrix is nxn matrix not nxm. This is the reason that i use that for definition